# Changing terminals at Dallas-Fort Worth airport (DFW)

Tags: layovers, short-connections, dfw

Landing in Terminal 1, taking off one hour later from Terminal 3. With only a one hour layover, will I have enough time to change terminals?

Comment: International or national arrival? Luggage rechecking or not? One ticket or separate tickets?

Comment: To make life easier, can you please also use the full name and/or city/country of the airport?

Comment: Sorry-new to this platform. All domestic within US- Flying into Dallas Fort Worth from Bozeman, MT, terminal 1. Leaving from terminal 3 one hour later to Charlotte, NC. I’m concerned about the short layover.

Comment: Please indicate whether this is a single ticket or two separate ones and whether you have checked luggage or not. It makes a huge difference .

Comment: @Hilmar Given the OP's lack of familiarity with SE, I think this line if questioning is over the top. It is quite uncommon in the US to arrive and depart on different tickets, and, if on the same ticket, where they is luggage it not is irrelevant since it is domestic US travel.

Comment: @Eric There are many sites now that list so-called "hacker fares" which in fact are separate flights pieced together by a search engine, so knowing the airlines and whether there is checked luggage is indeed highly relevant and hardly "over the top."

Comment: @Eric New users often don't understand that they should ask very detailed questions, and in the case of [travel.se] and new travelers, they might not even know which details might be important. The alternative to asking for those details is an unhelpful "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @MichaelHampton In this situation, the uncertainties could easily be handled by prefacing the answer with the assumptions being made. They are not likely enough to require the OP to provide the missing details prior to answering.

Answer (score 2):

DFW does not use numbers for terminals.  DFW uses letters.  So....

Presuming you mean Terminal A to Terminal C, yes.  If, almost certainly, American Airlines sold that itinerary as a single ticket, they expect you to make it and from experience, yes, it is enough time.

As soon as you enter the terminal, look for the SkyTrain signs.  Terminal C is the next terminal in the inner loop.

If you require mobility assistance, you can arrange that prior to departing for DFW.